# Wrong date format in IE 11 but correct in Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, date, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

In IE 11 the date is shown as English US (04.26.2016) 
In Edge the date is shown as Icelandic (26.04.2016) 
I also changed the language options in IE 11 but that didn't help.

Why are the browsers showing different date formats?

Comment: Are you able to provide screenshot examples? It might be the websites you are viewing format the date differently.

Comment: Well, Icelandic... More like [most of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country). This could be due to a localization related setting.